# Image not loading properly from the URL in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `Recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager`. The list items in the `Recyclerview` loads simple `JSON` from the URL containing `Name` and `Image URL`. I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2eYBtLWGzc&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=38) tutorial in order to load the image `asynchronously` from the received URL. When my app loads for the first time this is what I see.

[image: When I load the app for the first time]

And when I browse to another activity and come back this is what I see.
[image: When I browse other activities and come back]

This is my `Adapter` for `Recyclerview`

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private CategoriesViewHolder viewHolder;
    private ArrayList<Categories> categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public CategoriesAdapter(Context context){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
        imageLoader = volleySingleton.getImageLoader();
    }

    public void setCategoriesList(ArrayList<Categories> categoriesList){
        this.categoriesList = categoriesList;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, categoriesList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public CategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_list, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new CategoriesViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Categories current = categoriesList.get(position);
        viewHolder.categoryName.setText(current.categoryName);

        imageLoader.get(current.icon_url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                viewHolder.categoryIcon.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //viewHolder.contactIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoriesList.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my `VolleySingleton` class

```
public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton sInstance = null;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private VolleySingleton(){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getsInstance());
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024)/8);
            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getsInstance(){
        if(sInstance==null){
            sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getmRequestQueue(){
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
        return imageLoader;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all the heavy lifting yourself, I would personally recommend you to use this library, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Loading an image is as simple as this,

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Okay that worked. Thanks!! :) But I wanted to know what was the problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why you're seeing what you're seeing, but there are  problems that make this approach less than usable.

In `onBindViewHolder`:

1. Check to see if you already have the bitmap (e.g. in a memory cache). If it's there, call `ImageView.setImageBitmap`
2. If not, load it from disk or network *asynchronously*. When the load completes, instead of setting the view directly, update your memory cache and signal the adapter that the data set has changed (e.g. via `BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged`). Ideally, you only want to update the view that has changed, and `RecyclerView.Adapter` does allow this via `notifyItemChanged`. Both "notify" methods will result in `onBindViewHolder` being called and this time around, step 1 should succeed.

With that said, use a 3rd party library, as recommended by the earlier author (I'm partial to [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)). It makes things considerably easier and much less likely that you'll shoot yourself in the foot - and there are many issues with implementing custom image loading/caching.